# How to add tilt effect for canvas and image in wp7 mango

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to add tilt effect for canvas and Image. Can we do that or it is only possible for button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `Canvas` and `Image` is clickable element, put them inside a `Button` with customized style (without any chrome). It will provide tilt effect for free and release you from `OnMouseLeftButtonUp`-related issues.
If your `Canvas` is not a clickable element, why you need to do so?

BTW, it's possible to add tilt effect to any controls: `TiltEffect.TiltableItems.Add(typeof(YourControl));`

Comment: Better try putting control inside button, enabling tilt for custom controls giving lots of problems... thanks